# TSQL Get table results by joining the same table multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, left-join, common-table-expression

I have the following:

```
DECLARE @p_StartDate    DATETIME
DECLARE @p_EndDate      DATETIME

DECLARE @SC TABLE
(
TimeStamp DATETIME,
Action NVARCHAR,
StudyID INT NOT NULL,
ChamberID INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @SC (TimeStamp, Action, StudyID, ChamberID)
SELECT '2017-03-28 14:05:08.040', 'I', 155, 3335
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-28 14:05:08.047',   'I', 155, 3336
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-28 14:36:00.157',   'I', 155, 6418
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-30 13:15:04.607',   'I', 155, 3337
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-30 13:15:04.607',   'I', 155, 3338
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-04-04 13:40:28.580',   'D', 155, 3338
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-04-04 14:48:43.593',   'D', 155, 3337
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-04-17 20:56:07.540',   'D', 155, 3335
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-04-17 21:05:09.507',   'I', 155, 3335
```

Action = 'I' means allocated and 'D' means deallocated.

I need to find all the Chambers allocated to the Study given a query period. For instance, if @p_StartDate = '20170101' AND @p_EndDate = '20170102' then it should result nothing.

If @p_StartDate = '20170328' and @p_EndDate = '20170331' then the following should be returned:

```
ChamberId   DateAllocated 
3335        2017-03-28 14:05:08.040
3336        2017-03-28 14:05:08.047
6418        2017-03-28 14:36:00.157
3337        2017-03-30 13:15:04.607
3338        2017-03-30 13:15:04.607
```

If @p_StartDate = '20170328' and @p_EndDate = '20170431' then the following should be returned:

```
ChamberId   DateAllocated 
3335        2017-03-28 14:05:08.040
3336        2017-03-28 14:05:08.047
6418        2017-03-28 14:36:00.157
3337        2017-03-30 13:15:04.607
3338        2017-03-30 13:15:04.607
3335        2017-04-17 21:05:09.507
```

However if @p_StartDate = '20170418' and @p_EndDate = '20170431' then:

```
ChamberId   DateAllocated 
3336        2017-03-28 14:05:08.047
6418        2017-03-28 14:36:00.157
3335        2017-04-17 21:05:09.507
```

As the first time allocation for chamber 3335 was dealloacted on 2017-04-17 20:56:07.540, and chambers 3338 and 3337 were deallocated on 2017-04-04 13:40:28.580 and 2017-04-04 14:48:43.593 respectively.

I would like to avoid cursors if possible so I tried:

```
SELECT  A.TimeStamp, A.Action, A.StudyID, A.ChamberID
FROM    @SC A   
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM @SC
            WHERE Action = 'D'
        ) AS B
        ON A.ChamberID = B.ChamberID
        AND A.StudyID = B.StudyID
        AND A.TimeStamp < B.TimeStamp

WHERE (A.Action = 'I' AND A.TimeStamp < @p_EndDate)
AND NOT (A.Action = 'D' AND A.TimeStamp < @p_StartDate)
AND A.StudyID = 155
AND B.TimeStamp IS NULL
ORDER BY ChamberID
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is possible for a chamber to get allocated then deallocated and then allocated and then deallocated repeatedly for the same study.

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for your help. It is very close to what was required but there is one problem. I set the p_StartDate = '4/03/2017  1:15:05 PM'
p_EndDate = '4/18/2017  2:15:05 PM', then I should be getting Chamber 3337 back as well because 3337 was deallocated after the p_StartDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, the following should be (or be close to) what you need:

```
SELECT
    A.TimeStamp,
    A.Action,
    A.StudyID,
    A.ChamberID
FROM
    @SC A
WHERE
    a.Action = 'I'
    AND a.TimeStamp < @p_EndDate
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from @SC B
                    WHERE B.TimeStamp > a.Timestamp
                    AND B.TimeStamp < @p_StartDate
                    AND B.ChamberID = A.ChamberID
                    AND B.StudyID = A.StudyID --Note on this below
                    AND B.Action = 'D')
    AND A.StudyID = 155
ORDER BY
    A.TimeStamp
```

Try it at [rextester.com/SIFD43479](http://rextester.com/SIFD43479)

I'm not entirely sure whether the `<` operator is really what you want. Depending on your needs for that line you may need to convert the timestamp to a date (i.e. remove the time part) and use `<=` instead.

*Note*:
Not being familiar with what this data set represents or what exactly you are doing with it, it seems possible that the line `AND B.StudyID = A.StudyID` might be redundant, and perhaps in some circumstances could even cause erroneous results. If ChamberIDs are only ever deallocated in relation to a StudyID that they were previously allocated in relation to, and cannot be simultaneously allocated to two StudyIDs then I reckon it's fine as it is.

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for your help. It is very close to what was required but there is one problem.

Comment: I set the p_StartDate = '4/03/2017 1:15:05 PM' p_EndDate = '4/18/2017 2:15:05 PM', then I should be getting Chamber 3337 back as well because 3337 was deallocated after the p_StartDate.

Comment: This makes more sense to me know than when I first looked at it. Update on it's way.

Comment: Thanks Steve, worked perfectly! I also understood a bit more on how to use filter in subqueries. I didn't want to complicate the problem hence I didn't include other StudyIDs. It is perfectly possible for one chamber to be deallocated to one study and allocated to another therefore it is important that B.StudyID = A.StudyID.